# What does "entregar la cuchara" mean?

Tags: modismos, definiciones

This morning I was reading the news about [Spain's demise against Slovenia](https://elpais.com/deportes/2017/09/14/actualidad/1505413631_319224.html), and there was this expression that caught my eye:

> El equipo español, roto, hundido, **entregó la cuchara**.

This is the first time I've ever heard this in Spanish.
I've searched the DLE for [cuchara](http://dle.rae.es/?w=cuchara) and for [entregar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=entregar), but the saying *"entregar la cuchara"* does not appear in any of those entries.
I guess it means something along the lines of "to concede victory", but I want to be sure.

**What does *"entregar la cuchara"* mean?** Where does it come from and where is it used nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[He encontrado](https://www.forocoches.com/foro/showthread.php?t=1382693) [las negritas son mías en todos los párrafos]

> Como tantas otras expresiones, del ambiente militar, y específicamente del enfrentamiento entre las tropas mandadas por el Gran Capitán (Gonzalo de Córdoba) con los Jenízaros, una milicia de élite al servicio del Gran Turco. Estos Jenízaros llevaban en el gorro una cuchara de palo, que los españoles se preciaban de conseguir, previo apiolamiento del portador, por considerarla amuleto. Así pues, el turco muerto "entregaba la cuchara" y esta expresión pasó al lenguaje común con el **significado de morirse, o rendirse**.

y  en el mismo sitio, más abajo:

> Es una tradición levantina.
>   Antiguamente, cuando se hacía un "arroz en paella" (para los que lo desconocen, la paella es el recipiente), se utilizaba una sola cuchara de mader para todos los comensales.
>   Así la cuchara se pasaba de uno a otro y el gesto de "entregar la cuchara" se convirtió en el gesto de "**dejar paso al contrario**".

[Aquí](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/entregar-la-cuchara.924845/?hl=es) indican

> Especulando, podría estar relacionado con el torneo de rugby de las cinco naciones (hoy en día son seis naciones), en el que aquél **equipo que NO gana ningún partido** recibe una cuchara de madera.

y más abajo

> "Entregar la cuchara" es una expresión que se dice mucho por mi tierra, Andalucía, y **significa morir, el que entrega la cuchara es por que no va a comer más**, pero tambien se usa como podeis comprobar para indicar rendición o retirada.

Y [aquí](http://www.diariocordoba.com/noticias/opinion/entregar-cuchara-entregar-cucharas_934803.html)

> Coloquialmente, y con un poco de humor negro, en Córdoba se dice "entregar la cuchara" al **acto de morir**.

Finalmente, [aquí](http://romavictrix.blogspot.com.es/2008/10/el-sitio-de-malta-1565.html), describiendo el sitio de Malta en 1565:

> Curiosamente, a efectos del vocabulario español, la contienda sí tuvo efectos duraderos: Los jenízaros llevaban floridos gorros en cuyo frontal guardaban la cuchara de palo con la que comían; los soldados españoles codiciaban esta cuchara a la que consideraban un verdadero amuleto y registraban a los jenínaros muertos para despojarles de ellas. Desde entonces, "entregar la cuchara" es, para los españoles, **sinónimo de morir**.

En conjunto, parece que el significado es **morir** y/o **rendirse**.

Comment: esa segunda versión de la paella es una inventada. Lo dice el mismo que la postea al final de su entrada:  _«La historia que he escrito no es cierta, pero hoy estoy en un arranque de creatividad inconcebible»_

Comment: @walen: pero no está claro si son fuentes independientes

Answer (score 0):

No puedo decir de dónde viene la expresión, pero respondiendo a la pregunta principal parece que, originalmente, significaba **morir**:

> *No sabía que me he muerto; sí es verdad que por poco entrego la cuchara.*
>
> [Revista musical (Bilbao).](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004241757&page=21&search=%22entreg%C3%B3%20la%20cuchara%22&lang=es) 11/1911, n.º 11, página 21.

Sin embargo, con el tiempo pasó a significar **ceder, rendirse**. En el siguiente ejemplo vemos la necesidad del que escribe de explicar el eufemismo que estaba usando:

> *Estos compadres son el partido liberal, que hoy ejerce el cargo de* mayoral *en el cortijo del* turno, *y el partido conservador que entregó la* cuchara *(el poder) en el, por ahora, último cambio de política.*
>
> [El Siglo futuro.](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000339463&page=2&search=%22entreg%C3%B3%20la%20cuchara%22&lang=es) 21/6/1916, n.º 2.876, página 2.

Ambos ejemplos están sacados de la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España. No he podido encontrar ningún caso ni en el CORDE ni en el CREA.

Answer (score 0):

In Venezuela... this phrase refers to a woman who has had sexual relations with a man

Ejem "Luisa le entrego la cuchara a Luis"

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!